# cv2 imshow() window immediately closes on WSL2

Tags: opencv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, v4l2

I am using opencv-python in wsl2, and I can't have any images displayed. If I try to run the code below, a window with the correct image and name will open, but will close immediately.
If I try to run the same doce on cmd on windows, it works perfectly.

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

if img is None:
    print('Error loading image')
    exit()

cv2.imshow("title", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I also have problem, on my WSL2, with `cv2.VideoCapture()`, that works on Windows but not on the virtual machine displaying this error:
`[ WARN:0@2.573] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (889) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index`

I am using:
**Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**
**opencv-python: 4.5.5.64**

I don't know if these 2 problems are related or if I have to add another question.

Comment: the gui part might be a known issue (waitKey(0) not waiting, seems to receive spurious key events). I've seen talk of this before. -- the V4L part **is** a known issue. WSL can't pass camera devices into the VM. work natively if you can.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use cv2 and face_recognition lib, but face_recognition does not support windows.
There is any other python library for face recognition that I can use on windows?